# Pybullet Inverse Kinematics

Tags: python, robotics, bulletphysics, inverse-kinematics

I was very confused about usage of `calculateInverseKinematics()`function in pybullet environment. I have two simple questions:

1) How can we compute joint ranges to benefit from null space feature ?

Actually, I examined inverse kinematics code in the link: https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3/blob/master/examples/pybullet/examples/inverse_kinematics_husky_kuka.py

It seems as if range is computed by taking difference of upper and lower limits. In this case, I guess there is something wrong with jr[0] and jr[3].

2)

a) What is "joint damping coefficient" used for ?

b) Is there an effect of it on IK accuracy ?

c) How can we determine its values ?

I have made some research about these in pybullet guide document; however, I could not find something beneficial. If someone can explain them, I will appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on the same thing for about a year now.
Here are some answers from my findings:

a. joint damping coefficient => It is used to avoid higher joint velocities during singular configuration.
b. if the target is in reach it makes sure that it avoids the joint from oscillating near the target.
c. I think you have to change it in the code.

I am still working on it and if you wanna talk about it, it would be helpful for both of us.